# How to plot two leaves into a histogram (ROOT)?

Tags: root-framework

I have a file named “WW” that contains a tree named “mini” that contains leaves with information.

I want to write a script that reads this file and then plots multiple leaves into one histogram.

I have tried:

```
TFile *WW = new TFile("WW.root");
TTree* tWW = (TTree*) WW->Get("mini");

TCanvas *c1 = new TCanvas("c1",600,600);
c1->cd();
tWW -> Draw("leaf1");
tWW -> Draw ("leaf2","same");
```

This only plots one of the leaves, and not the second one on the same histo.
Thanks

Comment: do the variables in leaf1 and leaf2 cover the same range? (if left to default, the first draw sets range and binning for the histogram that's created and same uses the same binning and range for a second histogram that gets drawn onto the same canvas. so if leaf1 is between 0 and 1000, and leaf2 between 2000 and 3000 there's nothing to be seen.)

Comment: other sanity checks, are the distributions different and the lines of the two histograms maybe not sitting on top of each other? from the phrasing: do you really want both variables to be filled into the same histogram and thus end up with one histogram with twice the number of entries of the original tree? usually one would want to plot two histograms in the same canvas and end up with two lines to visually compare to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating two `TH1` objects and then draw with:

```
tree->Draw("variable >> histogram","goff")
```

Using goff. Then create the canvas and draw the histograms as `h1->Draw()` and `h2->Draw(" same")`.